# Handling bad URLs with requests

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

Sorry in advance for the beginner question. I'm just learning how to access web data in Python, and I'm having trouble understanding exception handling in the `requests` package.

So far, when accessing web data using the `urllib` package, I wrap the `urlopen` call in a try/except structure to catch bad URLs, like this:

```
import urllib, sys

url = 'https://httpbinTYPO.org/' # Note the typo in my URL

try: uh=urllib.urlopen(url)
except:
    print 'Failed to open url.'
    sys.exit()

text = uh.read()
print text
```

This is obviously kind of a crude way to do it, as it can mask all kinds of problems other than bad URLs.

From the documentation, I had sort of gathered that you could avoid the try/except structure when using the `requests` package, like this:

```
import requests, sys

url = 'https://httpbinTYPO.org/' # Note the typo in my URL

r = requests.get(url)
if r.raise_for_status() is not None:
    print 'Failed to open url.'
    sys.exit()

text = r.text
print text
```

However, this clearly doesn't work (throws an error and a traceback). What's the "right" (i.e., simple, elegant, Pythonic) way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to catch connection error:

```
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError

try:
    requests.get('https://httpbinTYPO.org/')
except ConnectionError:
    print 'Failed to open url.'
```

Comment: That worked. So, just to show my ignorance, in the following example (from the documentation), why does the `requests.get()` command not stop the execution:  `bad_r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/status/404')`. Why do we use `raise_for_status()` to see the error?

Comment: There are different types of "errors". If you make request using wrong `URL` (`URL` of non-existing web-application or incorrect `URL` construction) you'll get `ConnectionError`, `MissingSchema`... This errors means that your request cannot be sent. `HTTP-errors` is totally different type of errors. You can get `HTTP-error` (e.g. status-codes 401, 404, 500...) if your request constructed correctly and it can be sent, but target server cannot handle it in a way you expect. `python-request` doesn't raise exceptions in that case, so you can use `raise_for_status()` to do it

Comment: Got it. I understand the distinction now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a kind of exception after the keyword **except**.  So to catch just errors that come from bad connections, you can do:

```
import urllib, sys

url = 'https://httpbinTYPO.org/' # Note the typo in my URL

try: uh=urllib.urlopen(url)
except IOError:
    print 'Failed to open url.'
    sys.exit()

text = uh.read()
print text
```

Comment: Thanks, Bill. I have other reasons for wanting to learn how to use the `requests` package, but this helps to build my understanding of exception handling in general.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with that package, so I can't help with it.  But I hope someone else can help you!